# How to package an illustrator file with extendscript javascript?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, javascript

I have a lot of Illustrator files that I have to assemble (package) individually. I would like to know if it’s possible to do this with extendscript? I have found a function 'packageForPrin' in API InDesign that works very well but i don’t think it exists for Illustrator.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. Can you explain better your problem? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? As it is your question is too short for us guess what's the answer.

Comment: Sorry please excuse my english i am French. My problem is : I have a lot of illustrator files that i have to assemble (package) individually. I would like to know if it’s possible to do this with extendscript? I have found a function « packageForPrint » in API Indesign that works very well but i don’t think it exists for illustrator. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I should've said earlier, but you should [edit] your question to add that info

Comment: Does this help? https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/package-files.html

Comment: I like to do the same but with extendscript or applescript :/

Comment: There is a jsx that joins ai files (svg, pdf and eps also). I tested and I noticed that: it ignores hidden Layers. You have to specify the artboard dimensions in points (I think could edit it and change the mesurements to cm or inches, but not now.). The link to github: https://github.com/iconfinder/ai-merge

Comment: If you're asking if this can be done the answer is yes.  If you're asking for someone to write you a way to do this you should make an [edit] to demonstrate what you've tried and then we can proceed helping.  Right now your question is too broad for the community to understand what your goal is.  After completing an [edit] with clarity your question will be reviewed to see if it falls in scope then it will be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this! Maybe, with an AppleScript/ExtendScript(.jsx for short) one-two-punch-combo!
What we can do is invoke the Illustrator Package dialog with no fuss, by using this .jsx line: `app.executeMenuCommand ("Package Menu Item");`. So you can have your AppleScript do a `do javascript "app.executeMenuCommand ('Package Menu Item');"` and upon the result of this javascript, you will know the Package dialog is up. You may also be able to control what path is displayed in the dialog's destination folder input, and maybe what items are checked on/off, via changing Illustrator preferences through more .jsx lines: `app.preferences.setStringPreference(...)....` - but that syntax is a matter of another question. The thing to really test would be - after this dialog is up, if AppleScript can control it or do the most fundamental thing: press that "Package" button and make Illustrator do its packaging.

I'll see if I can make it happen on my Mac, based on this test I will edit this answer!